# Paramiko raising 'TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed' at the end of a script that uses `sftp.file/open`

Tags: python, postgresql, sftp, psycopg2, paramiko

I am writing a script to go pick up CSV files in a server and copy it inside of a PostgreSQL table. I can't find a way to work around an error raised by Paramiko when copying the file. I don't really understand the error, and I haven't found related posts that could help me solve this issue.

An SFTP connection works well, database remote access works well too, here is the problematic code chunk:

```
try:
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
    sftp = transport.open_sftp_client()
    print("SFTP Client : Open")
except Exception as e:
    msg = "Error connecting via ssh: %s" % e
    raise paramiko.SSHException(msg)

XT = "*.csv"
for filename in sftp.listdir(SSH_DIR):
    print(filename,'if-found')

    print("entered loop")
    path = '/%s/%s' % (SSH_DIR, filename)
   
    fobj = sftp.file(os.path.join(SSH_DIR,filename), 'rb')
    print(fobj)
    cur.execute('TRUNCATE TABLE %s' % TABLE_NAME)
    sql = "COPY %s FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER AS ','  csv header"
    table = 'my_table'
    cur.copy_expert(sql=sql % table, file=fobj)
    conn.commit()

transport.close()
```

and here is the error raised when executing the script

```
Database connected...
SSH connection succesful
SFTP Client : Open
kpis_inventory_analysis.csv if-found
entered loop
<paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile object at 0x7f0369d81f28>
Exception ignored in: <bound method SFTPFile.__del__ of <paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile object at 0x7f0369d81f28>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_file.py", line 76, in __del__
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_file.py", line 108, in _close
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the error occurs because you do not close the SFTP files. When the Python garbage collects the Paramiko objects representing the unclosed SFTP files at the end of the script, it fails, as the underlying SFTP connection is closed already.

Make sure you close the file after you stop using it:

```py
    with sftp.file(SSH_DIR + "/" + filename, 'rb') as fobj:
        print(fobj)
        cur.execute('TRUNCATE TABLE %s' % TABLE_NAME)
        sql = "COPY %s FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER AS ','  csv header"
        table = 'my_table'
        cur.copy_expert(sql=sql % table, file=fobj)
```

---

*Side note: Do not use `os.path.join` for SFTP paths. The SFTP paths needs to use the forward slash. While `os.path` uses a local system separator.*